# SparkKubernetesSensor failing cause SparkKubernetesOperator is already dead

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark, airflow

We have a Data Engineering project in which we basically use a Kubernetes cluster with SparkKubernetesOperator and SparkKubernetesSensor and Airflow orchestrating the tasks and workflow.

The problem is that sometimes task competition makes our infrastructure unable to trigger all tasks and sensors with the best synchrony in the world. Therefore, sometimes our SparkKubernetesOperator is triggered and its sensor is queued and takes so long to be triggered that, when it happens, the SparkKubernetesOperator is already dead and the sensor fails resulting in a 404 error, as it does not find the pod log from SparkKubernetesOperator.

Obviously we have an infrastructure bottleneck that causes this problem to happen. However, tinkering with it is not something we can do right away. So we are looking for some solutions that can help in the medium/short term.

The first alternative would be to increase the "timetoliveseconds" parameter in the pods to increase the possibility of the sensor finding the logs in a timely manner. However, we are not sure if the pod is alive for a long time it does not release the node's resources, creating another infrastructure bottleneck.

The second alternative would be an idea of ​​trying to force the sensor to run together with the operator, kind of creating a way in which they would only be triggered simultaneously, and not one after the other. And then that way only failures related to the code itself and not the lack of synchronism between the operator and the sensor would happen.The big problem is that we don't know if there is a way to do this, and if there is, we haven't found it yet.

Any suggestions?

LOG ERROR 404:

```
[2023-05-05, 13:24:15 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1300} INFO - Executing <Task(SparkKubernetesSensor): sensor_perfil_verificado_promo> on 2023-05-04 06:00:00+00:00
[2023-05-05, 13:24:15 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:55} INFO - Started process 20 to run task
[2023-05-05, 13:24:15 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:82} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'pipeline_best_choices', 'sensor_perfil_verificado_promo', 'scheduled__2023-05-04T06:00:00+00:00', '--job-id', '1280973', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/best-choices/dag-best-choices.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpqeronp7b']
[2023-05-05, 13:24:15 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:83} INFO - Job 1280973: Subtask sensor_perfil_verificado_promo
[2023-05-05, 13:24:15 UTC] {task_command.py:388} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: pipeline_best_choices.sensor_perfil_verificado_promo scheduled__2023-05-04T06:00:00+00:00 [running]> on host pipeline-best-choices-sensor-p-3534f4895f7a478a812050aa582b6258
[2023-05-05, 13:24:16 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:137} WARNING - /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/kubernetes/kube_config.py:39 DeprecationWarning: The delete_worker_pods option in [kubernetes] has been moved to the delete_worker_pods option in [kubernetes_executor] - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
[2023-05-05, 13:24:16 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:137} WARNING - /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/kubernetes/kube_config.py:41 DeprecationWarning: The delete_worker_pods_on_failure option in [kubernetes] has been moved to the delete_worker_pods_on_failure option in [kubernetes_executor] - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
[2023-05-05, 13:24:16 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:137} WARNING - /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/kubernetes/kube_config.py:44 DeprecationWarning: The worker_pods_creation_batch_size option in [kubernetes] has been moved to the worker_pods_creation_batch_size option in [kubernetes_executor] - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
[2023-05-05, 13:24:16 UTC] {pod_generator.py:424} WARNING - Model file  does not exist
[2023-05-05, 13:24:16 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1509} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=pipeline_best_choices
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=sensor_perfil_verificado_promo
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2023-05-04T06:00:00+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER=2
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=scheduled__2023-05-04T06:00:00+00:00
[2023-05-05, 13:24:16 UTC] {spark_kubernetes.py:105} INFO - Poking: dts-best-choices-perfil-verificado-promo-2023-05-05-12-42-06
[2023-05-05, 13:24:16 UTC] {base.py:73} INFO - Using connection ID 'kubernetes_default' for task execution.
[2023-05-05, 13:24:16 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1768} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/hooks/kubernetes.py", line 316, in get_custom_object
    group=group, version=version, namespace=namespace, plural=plural, name=name
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api/custom_objects_api.py", line 1484, in get_namespaced_custom_object
    return self.get_namespaced_custom_object_with_http_info(group, version, namespace, plural, name, **kwargs)  # noqa: E501
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api/custom_objects_api.py", line 1605, in get_namespaced_custom_object_with_http_info
    collection_formats=collection_formats)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 353, in call_api
    _preload_content, _request_timeout, _host)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 184, in __call_api
    _request_timeout=_request_timeout)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 377, in request
    headers=headers)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/rest.py", line 244, in GET
    query_params=query_params)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/rest.py", line 234, in request
    raise ApiException(http_resp=r)
kubernetes.client.exceptions.ApiException: (404)
Reason: Not Found
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Audit-Id': '41bcdf27-da7e-453b-a344-0fa82807af51', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, private', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-Kubernetes-Pf-Flowschema-Uid': 'ef02cbb8-3a78-4692-86aa-30128c75e9f8', 'X-Kubernetes-Pf-Prioritylevel-Uid': 'c8942bd1-20bc-4c28-b1b9-400500c532fc', 'Date': 'Fri, 05 May 2023 13:24:16 GMT', 'Content-Length': '366'})
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"sparkapplications.sparkoperator.k8s.io \"dts-best-choices-perfil-verificado-promo-2023-05-05-12-42-06\" not found","reason":"NotFound","details":{"name":"dts-best-choices-perfil-verificado-promo-2023-05-05-12-42-06","group":"sparkoperator.k8s.io","kind":"sparkapplications"},"code":404}



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/sensors/base.py", line 199, in execute
    poke_return = self.poke(context)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/sensors/spark_kubernetes.py", line 111, in poke
    namespace=self.namespace,
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/hooks/kubernetes.py", line 320, in get_custom_object
    raise AirflowException(f"Exception when calling -> get_custom_object: {e}\n")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Exception when calling -> get_custom_object: (404)
Reason: Not Found
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Audit-Id': '41bcdf27-da7e-453b-a344-0fa82807af51', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, private', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-Kubernetes-Pf-Flowschema-Uid': 'ef02cbb8-3a78-4692-86aa-30128c75e9f8', 'X-Kubernetes-Pf-Prioritylevel-Uid': 'c8942bd1-20bc-4c28-b1b9-400500c532fc', 'Date': 'Fri, 05 May 2023 13:24:16 GMT', 'Content-Length': '366'})
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"sparkapplications.sparkoperator.k8s.io \"dts-best-choices-perfil-verificado-promo-2023-05-05-12-42-06\" not found","reason":"NotFound","details":{"name":"dts-best-choices-perfil-verificado-promo-2023-05-05-12-42-06","group":"sparkoperator.k8s.io","kind":"sparkapplications"},"code":404}



[2023-05-05, 13:24:16 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1323} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=pipeline_best_choices, task_id=sensor_perfil_verificado_promo, execution_date=20230504T060000, start_date=20230505T132415, end_date=20230505T132416
[2023-05-05, 13:24:16 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:105} ERROR - Failed to execute job 1280973 for task sensor_perfil_verificado_promo (Exception when calling -> get_custom_object: (404)
Reason: Not Found
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Audit-Id': '41bcdf27-da7e-453b-a344-0fa82807af51', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, private', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-Kubernetes-Pf-Flowschema-Uid': 'ef02cbb8-3a78-4692-86aa-30128c75e9f8', 'X-Kubernetes-Pf-Prioritylevel-Uid': 'c8942bd1-20bc-4c28-b1b9-400500c532fc', 'Date': 'Fri, 05 May 2023 13:24:16 GMT', 'Content-Length': '366'})
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"sparkapplications.sparkoperator.k8s.io \"dts-best-choices-perfil-verificado-promo-2023-05-05-12-42-06\" not found","reason":"NotFound","details":{"name":"dts-best-choices-perfil-verificado-promo-2023-05-05-12-42-06","group":"sparkoperator.k8s.io","kind":"sparkapplications"},"code":404}


; 20)
[2023-05-05, 13:24:16 UTC] {local_task_job.py:208} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2023-05-05, 13:24:16 UTC] {taskinstance.py:2578} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. I increased the timetoliveseconds to 10 minutes... Decreased the amount of errors, but it still happens.

Comment: I managed to find my error by first trying to apply the same yaml that I pass to the SparkKubernetesOperator with `kubectl` : `kubectl apply -f <path-to-yaml>`, then I managed to get a more verbose error about why I was getting 404. For me, the issue was the `sparkapplications.sparkoperator.k8s.io` CRD was not installed properly

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, had anyone come to a good solution?
For now i just increase `max_active_runs` and `max_active_tasks` to improve the chances that the SparkKubernetesSensor will "catch" his matching SparkKubernetesOperator before it dies, but that is a very poor architecture to prevent this kind of race condition

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be sure to either convert this post into a comment when you get commenting privilege, or to turn it into a qualified answer (see [answer] for guidance)